# Singleton solution

Tags: java, methods, static, singleton

In [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html#6) blog:

> The code in Listing 10 does not use synchronization and ensures that
>   the Singleton object is not created until a call is made to the static
>   getInstance() method.

Isn't the above quote false? Since the static object is initialized early in the class, how is that the object is not created until a call is made to the static `getInstance()` method?

Comment: `getInstance()` is the only method available from a `static`-context of that class. For it's execution, that static initialization (hence the object creation) will be executed. So, no object is created before you call the static method.

Answer (score 4):

The code referenced in the question is essentially this:

```
class Singleton {
  private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

This *is* threadsafe, because the instance is not lazy initialized, rather it is instantiated once when the class is loaded.

The class loader imposes its own synchronization to guarantee that class initialization is threadsafe.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I consider the enum singleton pattern to be a misuse of enum (although it does work). I prefer the static inner class pattern, which gives lazy unit plus thread safety without any synchronization required - it's magic.

Comment: You should make `instance` final to guarantee to-to-date visibility to all threads.

Comment: @Bohemian An enum is specifically designed to let you specify all possible instances. I even use enum for utility classes to make it clear there should be no instances. Writing your own pattern can result in limiting to one instance but it's needlessly indirect, and error prone IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. I am well aware of the pattern you posted. But my question was, in the blog link I pasted,  why is the Singleton object not initiated until the getInstance() method is called? Aren't all static  objects initialized when the class is loaded?

Comment: What is the point of the getter? You can just make the static variable `public final` instead, right?

Comment: @Zoidberg you are completely correct, but the convention is to use a getter. Using a getter allows the implementation of returning the singleton flexible, for example if you wanted to change to a [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) in the future, you could easily make that change, but referencing the field directly means the imentation is locked to an eager initialization.